# add query results in a csv in linux

Tags: shell

I have a query in shell scripts that gives me a results like:

```
article;20200120
fruit;22
fish;23
```

I execute that report every day. I would like that when I execute the query the next day shows me output like that:

```
article;20200120;20200121
fruit;22;11
fish;23;12
```

These report I execute with postgre sql in a linux shell script. The output of csv is generated redirecting the ouput with ">>"
Please any help to achive that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

This might be somewhat fragile, but it sounds like what you want can be accomplished with [`cut`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) and [`paste`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html).

Let's start with two files we want to join:

```
$ cat f1.csv
article;20200120
fruit;22
fish;23

$ cat f2.csv
article;20200121
fruit;11
fish;12
```

We first use `cut` to strip the headers from the second file, then send that into `paste` with the first file to combine corresponding lines:

```
$ cut -d ';' -f 2- f2.csv | paste -d ';' f1.csv -
article;20200120;20200121
fruit;22;11
fish;23;12
```

Parsing that command line, the `-d ';'` tells `cut` to use semicolons as the delimiter (the default is tab), and `-f 2-` says to print the second and later fields.  `f2.csv` is the input file for `cut`.  Then the `-d ';'` similarly tells `paste` to use semicolons to join the lines, and `f1.csv -` are the two files to paste together, in that order, with `-` representing the input piped in using the `|` shell operator.

Now, like I say, this is somewhat fragile.  We're not matching the lines based on the header information, only their line number from the start of the file.  If some fields are optional, or the set of fields changes over time, this will silently produce garbage.  One way to mitigate that would be to first call `cut -d ';' -f 1` on each of the input files and insist the results are the same before combining them.